# Create n local bindings

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

Say we have something like this:

```
;list L of n procedure definitions, where a procedure definition is a list in form: 
;<name> <body>
;for example: ((n1 (+ 1 1)) (n2 (- 1 0)) (n3 (* 2 2))), where n = 3, n1 is the name of
;first procedure in list L and (+ 1 1) is its body.
```

Now I want n local bindings created. Based on the example above, something like this:

```
(define foo
(let* ((n1 (lambda () (+ 1 1)
       (n2 (lambda () (- 1 0)
       (n3 (lambda () (* 2 2))

(n1) ;newly defined procedure calls
(n2)
))
```

It's hardcoded in here, is there any way to create n local bindings without hardcoding them? Like reading the list of n procedures until it's empty and for each procedure definition inside, create a local bind of it inside let*?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the list `((n1 (+ 1 1)) (n2 (- 1 0)) (n3 (* 2 2)))` available at compile time or is it supplied by a user at run time?

Comment: @soegaard It's supplied by user at run time.

Comment: If so you can't introduce local bindings on runtime. This is not a Scheme/Racket restriction, but a general one. How would you refer to a binding in the program, if you don't know the name until runtime.

That said, maybe you can use hash tables instead? They provide a way to go from a name to a value (here a function).

Comment: @P.Lance it seems like you're coming to Racket from another language. You will have better success if you don't try to bring in your own style and set of conventions.

Comment: @soegaard omg I just reinstalled `planet neil/sicp` and i saw DrRacket fetching `soegaard/sicp`... This can't be a coincidence. What is your involvement with the project? I wouldn't even know where to dig around to find that answer on my own.

Comment: Once upon a time I ported the original MIT implementation of the picture language used in SICP to Racket (PLT Scheme at the time). Later (years later) I reimplemented the picture language in modern Racket. See https://github.com/sicp-lang/sicp/blob/master/sicp-pict2/sicp.rkt

Comment: Note that SICP support is available here: http://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/index.html?q=sicp

Comment: @soegaard very very cool. thank you for sharing. and um, thanks for all of your hard work on those projects! Racket community is refreshingly awesome.

Comment: @soegaard I see. Is it possible at compile time then? Perhaps I was aiming too high (or rather in the wrong direction haha).

Comment: Yes - at compile time you could use a macro. However - what is the higher goal you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a macro.

```
#lang racket
(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))

(define-syntax (define-locals stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_define-locals ([name expr] ...) body ...)
     #'(let ([name (lambda () expr)] ...) body ...)]))


(define-locals ((n1 (+ 1 1)) (n2 (- 1 0)) (n3 (* 2 2)))
  (list (n1)
        (n2)
        (n3)))
```

The result is:

```
'(2 1 4)
```